# How to compare 2 columns with lists in excel and highlight the non matching values?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have to Compare 2 lists in excel file and highlight the non matching entry corresponding to the cell value it was compared with. I was doing this for data validation purpose.

Example:

```
Column 1
1142103
36300
72600
121000
36300
60500
36300
3025
3025
8250

Column 2
230,000
36,300
72,600
121,000
36,300
60,500
36,300
3,025
***3,024***
8,250
```

Column 1 should be compared with column 2 and the non matching value in the 9th row/cell should be highlighted.

I have tried column difference option available in Home-Editing-Find&Select-GoToSpecial-Column Differences but that doesn't show the correct result since one column values have commas in them.

I tried to put commas to other column as well and use the column difference but still no use. I feel conditional formatting would be one option but I was able to compare only one row using the formula $A1<>$B1 and highlight with desired format, but this doesn't work for a range of cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it would be the opposite: compare column 2 to column 1.

You can use the built-in match function.

Suppose column 1 is "A" & column 2 is "B", in a third column "C", you can try:

```
=if(iserror(match(b2,$A$2:$A$11,0)),0,1)
```

That is, if there is no match, the output will be 0, and 1 otherwise. Then, you can apply a simple conditional format for Column C, where you highlight the cell if = 0.

P.S: there are almost always multiple solutions to an issue.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't have a flexibility to put some value to other column C. I am looking for something that can help me highlight the value which is not identical to the cell it was compared with.

Comment: The method I explained is among the easiest, but if your problem is that you can't get he correct result "since one column values have commas in them", why don't you use the find/replace box (ctrl+h), and replace the commas for none?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, feel free to up vote the question if it makes sense to you.